# How do I initiate a function at class initialization to set attributes within a child class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a model called `Row` below.. I have to create multiple models based off that one base model.

```
class Row:
    def __init__(self, 
             date=None, 
             cost=None, 
             currency=None):
        self.date = date
        self.cost = cost
        self.currency = currency

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "date": self.date,
            "cost": self.cost,
            "currency": self.currency
    }

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(Date: %s, Cost: %s, Currency: %s, ConversionRt: %s, CampaignId: %s)" % (self.__class__.__name__, 
                  self.date, self.cost, \
                  self.currency)
```

An example child class would be like follows:

```
class ChildRow(Row):
    def __init__(self, row, metrics):
        super().__init__(
            self.assign_rows(row, metrics)
        )

    def assign_rows(self,
                    row,
                    metrics):
        self.date = metrics['date']
        self.cost = metrics['cost']['amount']
        self.currency = row['localSpend']['currency']
```

The child class will need to accept multiple json response dictionaries and extract and assign certain parameters to each attribute.  For some reason I can't get this to work with the following payloads.  The attributes just will not set for some reason.

```
row = {'localSpend': {'currency': 'USD'}}
metrics = {'date': '20190401', 'cost': {'amount': 290.5999}}
```

What I'm expecting if I create an instance of `ChildRow` is that it automatically kicks off `assign_rows` and sets the data to the attributes. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?  The child class returns None for all attributes.  I'm also open to different or better modeling ideas. Thanks

Comment: Can you show how are you using `row` and `metrics` to instantiate the class, also your `__repr__` definition is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a strange understanding of how things work here. What your code does is the following:

- call `assign_rows`, which assigns the values of the instance attributes
- (implicitly) returns  None from that method
- passes that return value, ie None, into the parent class `__init__` method.
- that method takes that None value as the value of the `date` parameter. The other two parameters use their defaults, which are also None.
- All three None values are assigned to the instance attributes, overriding the values you previously set in `assign_rows`.

So in summary, the values *are* set, but are then overwritten with None.

I don't know why you think you need to pass the result of the function into the super call. The values are set; you can skip super altogether. Just do this:

```
class ChildRow(Row):
    def __init__(self, row, metrics):
        self.assign_rows(row, metrics)
```

Or, alternatively, move the logic out of `assign_rows` directly into `__init__`, and again skip calling super:

```
class ChildRow(Row):
    def __init__(self, row, metrics):
        self.date = metrics['date']
        self.cost = metrics['cost']['amount']
        self.currency = row['localSpend']['currency']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your purpose for adding the `assign_rows` function, but note that you're calling the base class constructor AFTER with the return value from `assign_rows` (which is always `None` as it returns nothing) so all your values are then overwritten with the defaults.

It would work like this (and it's cleaner):

```
class ChildRow(Row):
    def __init__(self, row, metrics):
        super().__init__(
            date=metrics['date']
            cost=metrics['cost']['amount']
            currency=row['localSpend']['currency']
        )
```